# What type of education should I select in this form?

Tags: phd, application

I am filling an application form for a PhD position and came upon this field:

[image]

It seems like a stupid question, but I am not familiar with this type of categorization. For a **Master's degree**, which one should I choose?

Comment: What happens if you select "Other"?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan nothing. It's just another option.

Comment: Where is the university you're applying to?

Comment: @JeffE in Austria

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that this application form is a generic "job application"-form, rather than one designed specifically for positions as PhD students. To my knowledge, PhD positions in Austria are categorized as jobs anyway.

Then, translating back to German, I suppose the cases are:

- Abitur/Matura
- Universitaetsabschluss (= university degree)
- Ausbildung

Thus, chose "study".

Comment: I would guess that "study" is just an awkward translation of "Studium".